# Нужен совет с помощью чего сверстать вот такой блок и как его застилить?

Tags: html

Есть вот такой блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно оформить блок с сылками, при наведении, кнопка становится активной.

```html
<div class="container"> 
         <div class="taxonomy-links" >        
                <ul class="menu">                
                    <li class="active_menu"><a href="#sales_taxonomy" class="block">ALL</li></a>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#Wordpress_taxonomy"class =
                        "button">Woordpres</a></li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#joomla_taxonomy"class =
                        "button">Joomla</a></li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#plugin_taxonomy"class =
                        "button">Plugins</a></li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#componant_taxonomy"class =
                        "button">Componant</a></li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#psd_taxonomy"class =
                        "button">PSD</a></li>               
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

И ведет на обзор все, следующая ведет на страницу и т.д.

Подскажите я в правильном направлении?

Comment: в стилях поставьте на класс button:hover { color: red; } ну или что там хотите

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.taxonomy-links .link').on('click', function() {
  $('.taxonomy-links .link').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.container .taxonomy-links ul li.link {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.container .taxonomy-links ul li.link:not(first-child) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.container .taxonomy-links ul li.link a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container .taxonomy-links ul li.link:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

.container .taxonomy-links ul li.link:hover {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .taxonomy-links ul li.link.active a {
  color: #fff;
}

.container .taxonomy-links ul li.link.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="taxonomy-links">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="link active"><a href="#sales_taxonomy" class="block">ALL</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a href="#Wordpress_taxonomy" class="button">Woordpres</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a href="#joomla_taxonomy" class="button">Joomla</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a href="#plugin_taxonomy" class="button">Plugins</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a href="#componant_taxonomy" class="button">Componant</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a href="#psd_taxonomy" class="button">PSD</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Там в вопросе ещё по наведению просили сделать.

Comment: @Дмитрий Полянин добавил пару стилей.

Comment: Ловите мой плюсик